# jQuery $(".class").click(); - multiple elements, click event once

Tags: jquery

I have multiple classes on a page of the same name. I then have a .click() event in my JS. What I want to happen is the click event only happen once, regardless of multiple classes on my page.

The scenario is that I am using AJAX to add to cart. Sometimes on the home page there might be a featured product and a top offer which means that the same class .add .#productid# is there and when clicked the add to cart AJAX is fired twice.

I thought about making 'click areas' so I would have .container-name .add .#pid# therefore giving unique clicks.

Is this the only solution?

```
<div class="addproduct 151">product info</div>
<div class="addproduct 151">product info</div>
<div class="addproduct 151">product info</div>
<div class="addproduct 151">product info</div>
<div class="addproduct 151">product info</div>


$(".addproduct").click(function(){//do something fired 5 times});
```

Comment: Please post your code, what you are saying doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Yes, post the code for your javascript please.

Comment: It should only fire once, its either a problem with your HTML - maybe one addproduct class is nested in another, or there is an error in the handler that fires the ajax twice for one click, either way we'd need so see more complete code to be sure.

Comment: horrible questioning and answering. i'm experiencing a similar issue but no where does the initial poster mention a resolve or method to the madness... so discouraging that people can't use this site properly but expect to be a developer on any level.

Comment: Use data-id="151" and then $(this).data('id')

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Apologies for bumping this old thread. I had the same problem right now, and I wanted to share my solution.

```
$(".yourButtonClass").on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    //(... rest of your JS code)
});
```

`event.StopPropagation` and `event.StopImmediatePropagation()` should do the trick.

Having a .class selector for Event handler will result in `bubbling` of click event (sometimes to Parent element, sometimes to Children elements in DOM).

`event.StopPropagation()` method ensures that event doesn't bubble to Parent elements, while `event.StopImmediatePropagation()`method ensures that event doesn't bubble to Children elements of desired class selector.

Sources:
https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/
https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

Comment: This is the right solution. If you call click on a class with jQuery it can bubble to other elements and register multiple clicks. Stopping the propagation of that click event to other elements is how to solve this. I think some of the other answers have misunderstood what was most likely happening here.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been looking for this the whole evening. This is the only answer that solves the problem. Was trying to get a correct 'click' listener for the Google Maps InfoWindow's element, which has the same '.gm-style-iw-a' class for all the markers in map. In my case, just using 'event.stopImmediatePropagation()' solved it.

Answer (score 108):

```
$(document).on('click', '.addproduct', function () {
    // your function here
});
```

Comment: does it work? never saw on function being used like this

Comment: How should i call the given answer from another event??

Comment: Tried everything, this is the only solution that worked.

Comment: Explanation of the second parameter: `A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.`

Answer (score 50):

Could we see your click handler? You're attaching 5 listeners to 5 different elements. However, when the user clicks on the element, only one event is fired.

```
$(".addproduct").click(function(){
  // Holds the product ID of the clicked element
  var productId = $(this).attr('class').replace('addproduct ', '');

  addToCart(productId);
});
```

If this solution doesn't work I'd like to look at your click handler.

Answer (score 28):

when you click div with addproduct class one event is fired for that particular element, not five. you're doing something wrong in you code if event is fired 5 times.

Comment: I love how this answer states the obvious and then the querent says they're going to check their code as if it weren't something they were going to do in the first place :D.

Comment: I'm surprised this is the accepted answer. As mentioned by Ivan Kalafatić, the issue is that the click event is being propagated to the other elements. The solution is to stop this propagation. Please see Ivan Kalafatić's answer for how to do that.

edit: just noticed the correct answer was actually written by Ivan Kalafatić and not Machavity (who edited it). Fixed my mistake.

Answer (score 17):

In this situation I would try:

```
$(document).on('click','.addproduct', function(){

    //your code here

 });
```

then, if you need to perform something in the other elements with the same class on click on one ot them you can loop through the elements:

```
$(document).on('click','.addproduct', function(){
   $('.addproduct').each( function(){

      //your code here
     }
  );
 }
);
```

Answer (score 11):

I think you add click event five times.
Try to count how many times you do this.

```
console.log('add click event')
$(".addproduct").click(function(){ });
```

Comment: Using AngularJS, I've noticed it's copied the script tag for testing x amount of times! Thanks for the possible solution.

Answer (score 8):

This should fix it and should be a good habit: .unbind()

```
$(".addproduct").unbind().click(function(){
   //do something 
});
```

Comment: Please note that unbind has been deprecated (from https://api.jquery.com/unbind): As of jQuery 3.0, .unbind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .off() method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by using inline jquery function call
 like

```
<input type="text" name="testfield" onClick="return testFunction(this)" /> 

<script>
  function testFunction(current){
     // your code go here
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You save my day Dude !

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem.
In my case PHP code generated few times the same jQuery code and that was the multiple trigger.

```
<a href="#popraw" class="report" rel="884(PHP MULTIPLE GENERATER NUMBERS)">Popraw / Zgłoś</a>
```

(PHP MULTIPLE GENERATER NUMBERS generated also the same code multiple times)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.report').click(function(){...});
</script>
```

My solution was to separate script in another php file and load that file ONE TIME.

Comment: Your comment led me to my solution - I had the same issue, one click fired an event for every element.  It was because I stuck the script in a partial view (asp mvc) that was loaded many times.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".addproduct").each(function(){
          $(this).unbind().click(function(){
               console.log('div is clicked, my content => ' + $(this).html());
           });
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addproduct 151">product info 1</div>
<div class="addproduct 151">product info 2</div>
<div class="addproduct 151">product info 3</div>
<div class="addproduct 151">product info 4</div>
<div class="addproduct 151">product info 5</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
The cause was that I had the same jquery several times. He was placed in a loop.

```
$ (". AddProduct"). click (function () {});
$ (". AddProduct"). click (function () {});
$ (". AddProduct"). click (function () {});
$ (". AddProduct"). click (function () {});
$ (". AddProduct"). click (function () {});
```

For this reason was firing multiple times

Answer (score 2):

Simply enter code hereIn JQuery,
ones event is triggered you just check number of occurrences of classes in file and use for loop for next logic.
for identify number of occurrences of any class, tag or any DOM element through JQuery :
var len = $(".addproduct").length;

```
 $(".addproduct").click(function(){
       var len = $(".addproduct").length; 
       for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
          ...
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do below code it's working absolute fine

```
$(".addproduct").on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    getRecord();
});


function getRecord(){
   $(".addproduct").each(function () {
       console.log("test");
       });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it myself in my project.

All my rows in a table have a class "contact":

[image: All my rows in a table have a class "contact".]

My code looks like this:

```js
var contactManager = {};

contactManager.showEditTools = function(row) {
  console.debug(row);
}

$('.contact').click(function(event){
  console.log("this should appear just once!");
  alert("I hope this will appear just once!");
  contactManager.showEditTools(event);
});
```

And I was first scared to see my whole rows as a result in the Firebug console when I executed the code:

[image: Firebug console screenshot after code execution]

But then I realized that the click event was not fired, because no alert-dialog appeared. Firebug shows you just the elements which are affected by the click overiding. So there is nothing to worry.

Answer (score 1):

Try making use of the `.off()` handler:

```
$(function () {
    $(".archive-link").click(function (e) {
        var linkObj = $(this);
        var cb = $("#confirm-modal");
        cb.find(".modal-body").append("<p>Warning message.</p>");
        cb.modal('show'); 
        cb.find(".confirm-yes").click(function () {
            $(this).off(); //detach this event
            //ajax call yada yada..
        }
```

I attach a click event handler on an OK modal button to act on `click` event of the object with class `.archive-link`.

On the first click, the event fires only on that `.archive-link` object that I asked the function to act on (`var linkObj`). But when I click the same link the second time and hit OK on the modal, the event fires on every object that has `.archive-link` that I clicked before.

I used the solutions above but unfortunately did not work. It was when I called .off() within the modal OK button click function that the propagation stopped. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This question have been resolved and also got a lot of responses, but i want to add something to it.
I was trying to figure out, why my click element his firing 77 times, and not one time.

in my code, i had an each, running a json response and displaying it as divs with buttons. And then i declared the click event inside the each.

```
$(data).each(function(){
    button = $('<button>');
    button.addClass('test-button');
    button.appendTo("body");

    $('.test-button').click(function(){
        console.log('i was clicked');
    })
})
```

If you write your your code like this, the class .test-button will get multiple click events. For example, my data has 77 lines, so the each will run 77 times, that means i will decline the click event on the class 77 times. When you click the element, it will be fired 77 times.

But if you wirte it like this:

```
$(data).each(function(){
    button = $('<button>');
    button.addClass('test-button');
    button.appendTo("body");
})

    $('.test-button').click(function(){
        console.log('i was clicked');
    })
```

you are declaring the click element after the each. That means, the each will run its 77 times, and the click element will be declared only one time. So, if you click the element, it will be fired only one time.

Answer (score 1):

Hi sorry for bump this post just face this problem and i would like to show my case.

My code look like this.

```
<button onClick="product.delete('1')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
<button onClick="product.delete('2')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
<button onClick="product.delete('3')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
<button onClick="product.delete('4')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

Javascript code

```
<script>
 var product = {
     //  Define your function
     'add':(product_id)=>{
          //  Do some thing here
     },

     'delete':(product_id)=>{
         //  Do some thig here
     }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

class name denoted by dot(.) and click method will trigger when you will click on where you given class name addproduct.

```js
$(".addproduct").click(function(){
  //your logic on click
  console.log("clicked");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addproduct 151">product info</div>
<div class="addproduct 151">product info</div>
<div class="addproduct 151">product info</div>
<div class="addproduct 151">product info</div>
<div class="addproduct 151">product info</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have found, when I am creating multiple duplicate elements with javascript and inject them into the HTML on page load, Jquery .click() does not work.

In this case, attach an onClick tag to the html element when you generate the element in javascript

```
$("#items").html('<button onClick="delete_item(`'+item+'`)" value="'+item+'">Remove</button>');
```

Then later, when you click this button, it will execute the delete_item() function and pass `this` into it for use later.

```
function delete_item(item){

    console.log(item);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only answer for this.

```
$(document).on('click', '.addproduct', function() {
  // your function here
});
```

Answer (score -4):

your event is triggered only once...
so this code may work
try this

```
    $(".addproduct,.addproduct,.addproduct,.addproduct,.addproduct").click(function(){//do     something fired 5 times});
```