# innerhtml+= How to Get load data from ajax then make an action?

Tags: php, html, ajax

im newbie that newbie learn here...

i want add some event from loaded part dynamically but it return to 1 id

so i problem with innerHTML+= and call with ajax like this..

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: 'getuser.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        id_user: id_user
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                       listuser.innerHTML+=data;
                      
                    }
                  
                });
```

then with getuser.php i got result like this

```
<div id="listuser">
<button id="1" class="pickmember">Member1</button >
<button id="2" class="pickmember">Member2</button>
</div>
```

so when i call a function

```
$(".pickmember").click(function(){
var id_user=$(this).attr('id');
alert('u pick member'+id_user);
});
```

when i call it,, it always return to last added to innerhtml, and cant detect member2 when click,, there is solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried `listuser.innerHTML = listuser.innerHTML + data`?

Comment: Go jquery all the way `$('#listuser).append(data);`

Comment: yea sure,, its return same as code above....

Comment: @FelippeDuarte i done tried this too,, its same result as above ...

Comment: When you add a new DOM element you need to rebind the click function. Run the same `.click()` after you append `data`

Comment: After use append. Somehow  class didnt add the event click

Comment: Hi try like this `$(document).on("click",".pickmember",function(){
alert($(this).attr('id'))})` see if that alert showing correct value .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .on() instead of .click()

```
$(".pickmember").on('click', function () {
    var id_user = $(this).attr('id');
    alert('u pick member' + id_user);
  });
```

more information --> [jQuery $(".class").click(); - multiple elements, click event once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563783/jquery-class-click-multiple-elements-click-event-once)

Comment: Try adding event.stopPropagation();  and   event.stopImmediatePropagation();

Comment: its still return to id member1 ... so frustate